# Configuring Fluent NHibernate with System.Data.OracleClient

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to use System.Data.OracleClient instead of Oracle.DataAccess with Fluent Nhibernate .  From what I understand, in order to achieve this I should change my driver from OracleDataClientDriver to OracleClientDriver.  I've configured it like below, but I get an error that looks like it is still trying to use OracleDataClientDriver.  What am I doing wrong?

```
FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()                
            .Database(
            OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10
            .ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connString))
            .Provider<NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider>()
            .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver>()            
               )
```

Here is the error, it is still looking for Oracle.DataAccess which I'm trying to get away from.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver..ctor() +134

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +232
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6
   NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type type) +58
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) +194

[HibernateException: Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.]
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2 settings) +334
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2 settings) +233
   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2 settings) +558
   NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties) +1328
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings() +85
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +102
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() +72
```

Comment: I believe you should also change OracleDataClientConfiguration to OracleClientConfiguration

Comment: Please note that Microsoft deprecated the System.Data.OracleClient and recommends that you use a third-party Oracle provider instead.

Comment: Ideally I would move away from System.Data.OracleClient but as you know sometimes in the real world you're limited by your environment :(  Rivarolle, post your answer so I can give you credit.  Cannot believe I overlooked that.  I just gave my face a high five.

Comment: @PapaBurgundy did you solve your problem, it where great if you have a solution

Comment: @Higune I did.  Take a look at the comments above.  There were 2 places I had to change it.  The end result should use OracleClientConfiguration and OracleClientDriver instead of OracleDataClientConfiguration and OracleDataClientDriver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **OracleClientConfiguration** and **OracleClientDriver** *instead of OracleDataClientConfiguration and OracleDataClientDriver*

```
FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure()                
            .Database(
            OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
            .ConnectionString(x => x.FromConnectionStringWithKey(connString))
            .Provider<NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider>()
            .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver>()            
               )
```

---

The comments in the question solved my problem. I've posted this answer for the benefit of others, @PapaBurgundy & @Rivarolle deserve full credit for the answer.

Comment: This answer gave me the place to fix it.  In my case, I needed "NHibernate.Driver.OracleManagedDataClientDriver".       Full context of my fix :             _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(OracleDataClientConfiguration
                .Oracle10
                .ConnectionString(c => c.Is(myConnectionString))
                .Provider<NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider>()
                .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OracleManagedDataClientDriver>()
              )